# Angular - Problem with async reactive form validator

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, asynchronous, angular-reactive-forms

The problem I have is that I want to make a call to a service that makes an http call to an API and checks whether or not the username given exists.

Code from Auth:

`usernameCheck(username: string){
  return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "usernamecheck?username=" + username);
}`

Code from controller:

```
async usernameExistsValidator(g: FormGroup){
const username = g.get("username").value;
let username_exists: boolean;
if(username){
  await this.authService.usernameCheck(username).toPromise()
    .then(
      (res : any) => {
        username_exists = res.exists;
      }
    )
  console.log(username_exists)
  return username_exists ? { usernameExistsError: true } : null; 
}
```

The main problem is that I get the correct console.log value but the return does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Pause till the promise resolves with **[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)**,
so change this

```
await this.authService.usernameCheck(username).toPromise()
    .then(
      (res : any) => {
        username_exists = res.exists;
      }
    )
  console.log(username_exists)
```

by

```
   const res = await this.authService.usernameCheck(username).toPromise()

   username_exists = res.exists;

   console.log(username_exists)
```

Comment: Okey thanks, but when I do the return it is still not working, do you know why?

Comment: can you post the result of console.log(res)